# Need a way to kill/end threads in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am building an audio player using python and Vosk. I have implemented threading to listen out for user commands while it plays music.

The threads are being made in a loop, and more threads are made every time the program repeats itself.

```
import threading

while True:

   data = q.get() #Gets element from a queue which incoming messages are stored in
   message = data.translate() #Translates the message into words

   for x in keywords: #Sorts through a list of specific keywords
      if x in message:
         def playMusic(music): #This function plays music
            while stopp.is_set() 
               music.play()
            music.stop()
            return
         def listen(): #This function listens for user commands
            stopp.set()
            while stopp.is_set():
               data = q.get()
               stopmessage = data.translate()
               if 'stop' in stopmessage: 
                  stopp.clear()
                  return

         play = threading.Thread(target=playMusic, daemon=True) 
         check = threading.Thread(target=listen, daemon=True)
         stopp = threading.Event() 
         check.start() 
         play.start()
```

The problem is, every time the music either finishes or stopped by the user, it is all repeated. Every time that happens, the number of threads in the program increases, as the previous threads do not end but new ones are created.

I have been unable to find a way to terminate the threads. I have tried using return, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your threading code runs in a for and an endless while loop. You should get it out of there, so in each looping step you will launch another thread. Just wondering: if listen is your controlling function, souldn't it be run as the main app and play being in a thread?

Comment: (1) At the end of the `if x in message:` block there should be a `break` to ensure that at most one iteration of the for-loop starts threads. (2) After threads are started, main thread and listen thread(s) both wait for messages with `q.get()`. If the wrong thread receives the wrong message it isn't processed correctly.